# What is the difference between BufferManager and System.Buffers.ArrayPool in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, memory, memory-management

In what scenarios should we prefer one over other? It appears like [BufferManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager) is not optimal for pooling large sizes of memory. Is that true?

[ArrayPool Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BufferManager` works only with buffers i.e. arrays of type byte[], while `ArrayPool` can work with any type of array as it's a generic type. Their capabilities from the memory size perspective are quite similar.